# Make some rows read-only

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I want to make some rows in a LibreOffice Calc file read-only. I select the rows and then go to Format > Cells... then to Cell Protection tab but this does not appears to be the place. The Protected checkbox is already checked and has no effect on the rows.

How do I do this?

[image]

LibreOffice
Version: 6.4.6.2
Build ID: 1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
CPU threads: 8; OS: Linux 5.4; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3;
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); UI-Language: en-US
Calc: threaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Protected" option in cell properties doesn't toggle cell protection directly. It just marks cells **that should be protected *if the sheet is protected***. Protecting every cell if the sheet is protected is the default. So, you'll have to *modify only those cells that shouldn't be protected* if the sheet is protected.

Thus, the dialog window tells: "Cell protection is only effective after the current sheet has been protected." and "Select 'Protect Sheet' from the Tools menu."

So, the expected workflow is:

1. edit your sheet;
2. *optional*: select which cells **shouldn't** be protected (default: all cells protected, thus you'll have to "unprotect" the cells that should be editable; use `Cell Protection` Tab in `Format Cells` window);
3. enable sheet protection using Menu `Tools` -> `Protect Sheet`, setting the password and the user privileges (inserting / deleting cells, selecting protected / unprotected cells).

Comment: I'm still not getting it. What do I do at step 2? Do I select the rows I want protected or the rows I do not want protected?

Comment: @AlLelopath: The rows you **don't** want to protect. The default is that every cell is protected if the sheet is protected. So, if you want to protect the entire sheet, you can skip step 2. Only if you want to exclude some cells (rows, columns) from protection, you need to deactivate "Protected" in their Format settings. I've modified my answer, that wasn't in fact clear - sorry! –